# Show that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}y_n=x$, if $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=x$ and $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}z_n=x$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Condition: $x_n\leq y_n\leq z_n$ for all $n \geq N$, $N \in \mathbb{N}$

My thinking is:

$x_n - y_n \leq x_n - z_n$ because $y_n\geq z_n$

$x_n - y_n \geq 0 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~$because $x_n  \geq y_n$

While

$x_n - z_n \overset{n}{\to} 0$

So it seems obvious, that (!!! not sure how to prove this!!!):

$x_n - y_n \overset{n}{\to} 0$

Which means that:

$x_n \overset{n}{\to} x$

Comment: Suppose $a_n \ge 0$, $a_n \ge b_n$ and $b_n \to 0$. Let $\epsilon>0$, then for some $N$, you have $0 \le b_n < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. Then you have $0 \le a_n \le b_n < \epsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. Hence $a_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The statement $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$ is shorthand for: $\forall \epsilon, \exists N_1$, such that $\forall n > N_1, \ \ |x_n - x| < \epsilon$.

Similarly  $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} z_n = x$ is shorthand for: $\forall \epsilon, \exists N_2$, such that $\forall n > N_2, \ \ |z_n - x| < \epsilon$.

You are also also told that $x_n\leq y_n\leq z_n$ for all $n \geq N$, $N \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now choose $N_m = \max(N_1,N_2,N)$, then it is true that for all $n>N_m$, we are in a range where all three statements are true. We can combine them to obtain

$\qquad x - \epsilon < x_n \leq y_n \leq z_n < x + \epsilon$,

which means

$\qquad |y_n -x | < \epsilon$,

so we have shown that $\forall \epsilon, \exists N_m$, such that $\forall n > N_m, \ \ |y_n - x| < \epsilon$, which is the same as $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = x$.